# Comparación de muchos valores Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente problema: estoy obteniendo valores de varios select y los estoy guardando en variables para luego hacer la comparación en el if y mosotrar el resultado. Esto es para un cotizador utilizando funciones en javascript.

El problema esta en que busco la manera de optimizar esto, ya que no me resulta muy practico.

```
else if ((x== 2 && d == 1 && e== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && f== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && g== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && h== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && i== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && j== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && k== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && k== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && d == 1 && k== 1) ||

         (x== 2 && e == 1 && d== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && f== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && g== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && h== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && i== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && j== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && k== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && l== 1) ||
         (x== 2 && e == 1 && m== 1) ||
         


 )




 {


//modulo1
document.getElementById("cant1").innerHTML = "$75,000.00";
document.getElementById("cant2").innerHTML = "$75,000.00";
document.getElementById("cant3").innerHTML = "$45,000,00";
document.getElementById("cant4").innerHTML = "$45,000,00";

}
```

Comment: Veo que "x" se repite, algunos valores dependen o se comparan basados en los valores de otros?.

Ademas estas repitiendo código por ejemplo:
(x== 2 && d == 1 && e== 1) y (x== 2 && e == 1 && d== 1) son básicamente lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista con algunos for podrias optimizar eso, fijate que x && d, x && e se repiten una cierta cantidad de veces, luego dentro deberias hacer esas operaciones comparativas